# JSch SFTP upload/download progress

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I am new to JSch and Java. I managed to get some code and understand it somehow, but I am stuck on one point. The following code downloads file from SSH/SFTP server, but I am in need of the progress meter that shows percentage of file copied. How can I do it?

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpProgressMonitor; 
public class SFTPExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String user = "root";
        String password = "password";
        String host = "192.168.0.5";
        int port = 22;
        String knownHostsFilename = "/home/world/.ssh/known_hosts";        
        String sourcePath = "/media/nfs/genotype.txt";
        String destPath = "genotype.txt";        
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHostsFilename);
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect(); 
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        sftpChannel.connect();
            
        System.out.println("Downloading test file");
        sftpChannel.get(sourcePath, destPath);            
        
        sftpChannel.exit();
        session.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are overloads of the `get`/`put` methods in the [`com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) that you use to pass in a callback. Look at the

```
void get(java.lang.String src, java.lang.String dst, SftpProgressMonitor monitor)
```

method and [`com.jcraft.jsch.SftpProgressMonitor`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpProgressMonitor.html) interface. At the bottom of this [Example Code](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java) (it's kind of messy), you'll find an implementation of `SftpProgressMonitor` that uses its callback methods `count(long)` and `end()` to manipulate a [`javax.swing.ProgressMonitor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html).

`count(long)` gets called periodically when there's some bytes that have been transferred, and `end()` gets called when the transfer has ended. So a really simple implementation of `SftpProgressMonitor` could be:

```
public class SystemOutProgressMonitor implements SftpProgressMonitor
{
    public SystemOutProgressMonitor() {;}

    public void init(int op, java.lang.String src, java.lang.String dest, long max) 
    {
        System.out.println("STARTING: " + op + " " + src + " -> " + dest + " total: " + max);
    }

    public boolean count(long bytes)
    {
        for(int x=0; x < bytes; x++) {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        return(true);
    }

    public void end()
    {
        System.out.println("\nFINISHED!");
    }
}
```

I'd then create an instance of that and pass it to `get()`

```
sftpChannel.get(sourcePath, destPath, new SystemOutProgressMonitor());
```

Comment: thanx fo the answer..
If I am downloading file of 100MB at that time my bytes value is : 32755 like,,.so would you explain me why I am getting this value..

Comment: You can get the size of the total transferred data by cumulating that given value.